# how to merge a multiple of rows into one row and name it in Pandas?

Tags: python

I have a dataframe:

```
age sex country 
25   m   USA
30   f   Canada
65   f   china
42   m   Indonesia
32   f   mexico
```

I want to convert the country to 2 categories and then I want to generate 2 columns of dummy variables:

```
North America=(USA, Canada, Mexico).
Asia= (China, Indonesia)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a single column named `continent` and get your result:-

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'age':[25,23,26], 'sex':['m','f','f'], 'country': 
['mexico','china','usa']})

north_america = ['usa','mexico','canada']
asia = ['china','indonesia']

def change(country):
    if country in north_america:
        return "North America"
    elif country in asia:
        return "Asia"


df['continent'] = df['country'].apply(change)
df
```

**Output**

```
       age  sex country continent
   0    25  m   mexico  North America
   1    23  f   china   Asia
   2    26  f   usa North America
```

Comment: @Saja I have checked it again, it is giving the correct result.

Comment: @Saja are you getting None value in `continent` colomn.